# How to join the array element based on condition?

Tags: python, list

How to get the element between dynamically

```
def hello(self):\n
# And
def hello2(self):\n

# And join into
def hello(self):\n
```

And then get the element between

```
def hello2(self):\n
# And
def hello3(self):\n

# And join into 
def hello2(self):\n
```

The containDef is get from file:

```
with open("test70.py", "r") as a_file:
```

What are the ways to achieve :

```
containDEF = ['def hello(self):\n\ttry:\n\t\tglobal testcaseResult\n\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n\t=self.MOSSIOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n','def hello2(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n','def hello3(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n']
```

I am currently getting :

```
containDEF = ['def hello(self):\n', '\ttry:\n', '\t\tglobal testcaseResult\n', '\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n', '\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n','\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n','def hello2(self):\n', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n', 'def hello3(self):\n', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n']
```

Comment: I think you shold read [ask]! , I personally didn't understand what you are asking, can you please explain clearly

Comment: Why are you using lists of strings to parse Python? As I said last night, I suggest you use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the tool suggested by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar). But still if you wanna do it manually do the following:

```py
containDEF = ['def hello(self):\n', '\ttry:\n', '\t\tglobal testcaseResult\n',
              '\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n', 
              '\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n','\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n',
              'def hello2(self):\n', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n', 
              'def hello3(self):\n', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n']

indexes = [containDEF.index('def hello2(self):\n'),containDEF.index('def hello3(self):\n')]    # stores the indexes of the stop points

newList = []    # will store the reuslts
start = 0  
for i in range(0,len(indexes)+1):
    string = ''     # renewed on each iteration 
    if(i == len(indexes)):
        end = None
    else:
        end = indexes[i]
    for j in containDEF[start:end]:    # gets the string between the start and end points
        string += j    # joins the string between those points
    newList.append(string)    # appends to the new list
    start = end
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the `indexes = [containDEF.index('def hello2(self):\n'),containDEF.index('def hello3(self):\n')]    # stores the indexes of the stop points` dynamically because the `containDEF = []`  is actually get from .py file 
`with open("test70.py", "r") as a_file:` so in future there will be def hello5() update to the file

Comment: You have managed to store that file information in a list don't know how you did that now you can always get the index by using `list_name.index[item_name]`.You could have done the same with strings but in strings. but i guess your main problem will be to split these functions into list items.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want something like this, if not please explain with a little more details..

```
lst = [
    "def hello(self):\n",
    "\ttry:\n",
    "\t\tglobal testcaseResult\n",
    "\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n",
    "\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n",
    "\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n",
    "def hello2(self):\n",
    "\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n",
    "def hello3(self):\n",
    "\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)\n",
]


def get_lists_between(from_element, to_element, lst):
    first = lst.index(from_element)
    second = lst.index(to_element)
    return lst[first:second]


def add_to_lst_item(addition, item, lst):
    lst[lst.index(item)] += str(addition)


h = "def hello(self):\n"
h2 = "def hello2(self):\n"
h3 = "def hello3(self):\n"

add1 = get_lists_between(h, h2, lst)
add_to_lst_item(add1, h, lst)

add2 = get_lists_between(h2, h3, lst)
add_to_lst_item(add2, h2, lst)
```

Comment: The 1st =[] is actually read from a file `with open("test70.py", "r") as a_file:`
how to get these dynamically
`h = "def hello(self):\n"
h2 = "def hello2(self):\n"
h3 = "def hello3(self):\n"`
so in future there will be added `def hello4, def hello5`